# Filtered response does not show total records in response of REST APIs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, search-criteria

I am using **GET V1/products** endpoint to fetch product list. I want to fetch sku and name only.

```
http://localhost/magento/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC&currencyCode=USD&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&fields=items[name,sku]
```

**response**

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "sku": "5245",
        "name": "Test Product"
    },
    {
        "sku": "product 1",
        "name": "product 1"
    },
    {
        "sku": "product 2",
        "name": "product 2"
    },
  ]
}
```

I am not getting total number of records in this response. I checked it on devdocs as well. It also has same type of response, please find link below.

[Magento filtered response](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/retrieve-filtered-responses.html#using-with-searchcriteria)

Please help if anyone already faced this and solved it.

Comment: sorry man but this link not helped me.

Comment: which magento version you have? you may find issue [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17295)

Comment: I am getting total_count key in local(magento 2.2.6) which magento version you have? try http://magento225.sr/swagger#/catalogProductRepositoryV1/catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGet

Comment: Thank you man, I found the solution and posted here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, I checked some core files of catalog module and I can see that search criteria and total records are not in items index  so I just need to update my request like below.

```
http://localhost/magento/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC&currencyCode=USD&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&fields=items[name,sku],total_count
```

I hope it'll help others, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Welcome @AdityaShah

Comment: Suthan, thanks for your answer, can you please help, how can we can available filters with the result?

Answer (score 4):

You need to select total count too to fetch it. Add total_count at the end of your request like this:

```
REQUEST,total_count
```

Comment: Thanks Kamal, I already found the solution and your solution is same what I did :)

Comment: Welcome @AdityaShah